# Does MySQL error "Illegal mix of collations" imply an SQL injection vulnerability?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

The user input of a given query is being sanitized (PHP, real_escape_string), yet the query fails with "Illegal mix of collations". This query is below:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` = "�½��ļ���.zip"
```

Does this imply that this query is vulnerable to SQL Injection? If not, is there any disclosure or other vulnerability that this input may provide the attacker?

**Edit:** This particular request appears to have come from Acunetix Vulnerability Scanner. If this is accurate, there must be some value to an attacker in providing this value in a request. What results might the scanner have been expecting?

Comment: No it does not indicate SQL injection. This error simply states that two strings of incompatible collations are being compared. In this scenario the input with the column data.

Comment: That said you should use [prepared-statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)